# Local Ortho projection to Proj4

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj, epsg

We are trying to use proj4 to project a local coordinate system to EPSG4326. We believe we have most of the string created correctly in QGIS and as follows;

```
+proj=ortho +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=40.52741251 +lon_0=-117.12455304 +x_0=372979.646 +y_0=103881.838 +units=us-ft no_defs
```

We are missing azimuth and scale. I believe we can use `+k` or `_k_0` for scale but cannot determine how azimuth is defined. Are these incorporated into such a projection in proj4?
We have also run the ESRI equivalent prj through GDAL srsinfo with the following output:

```
PROJ.4 : ERROR 6: No translation for LOCAL to PROJ.4 format is known.

Local system params in ESRI.prj;

Projection: Local
Scale_Factor:   1.00024937
Azimuth:    -0.31500000
```

Answer (score 4):

The Proj.4 definition of the orthographic projection does not use scale or azimuth values: http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/orthographic.html

If you need a rotated local coordinate system, you better use an oblique mercator projection.

See my answer to this topic for an example: [Using customized Coordinate System in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83861/using-customized-coordinate-system-for-archaeological-site-data)

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940941/wkt-equivalent-of-local-projection

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Ortho-Projection-Question-td3841014.html

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003r00000035000000

In the last source, you can read that the ESRI `Local` projection suffers heavy distortion away from the center, so changing the projection to omerc is not a bad idea.

Comment: Does the x_0 and Y_0 have to be in meters?

Comment: Yes: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118215/proj4-string-for-nad832011-louisiana-south-ftus/118244#118244 . That is the major difference to the ESRI .prj file WKT definition.