# Using North Pole Orthogonal projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, arctic

I was looking for the North Pole Orthogonal projection in QGIS but I haven't found it yet.

Is there any way to add this projection in CRS?

Comment: Are you looking for a North Pole Orthographic projection? See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143154/local-ortho-projection-to-proj4 for an example.