# pyproj does not properly convert EPSG:3760 to WGS 84

Tags: pyproj

I have coordinates stored in EPSG:3760. I can use https://epsg.io/transform to transform these properly to WGS 84 GPS coordinates, like so:

[image: Transforming EPSG:3760 coordinates using https://epsg.io]

As seen in the photo, my coordinates (1728779.950564162, 81827.07350218101) are successfully converted to GPS (-157.7402677, 21.3917278). I have verified these coordinates using a map.

Trying to use pyproj, however, gives me a different result.

```
>>> import pyproj
>>> pyproj.__version__
'1.9.5.1'
>>>
>>> p1 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3760')
>>> p2 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')
>>>
>>> x = 1728779.950564162
>>> y = 81827.07350218101
>>>
>>> pyproj.transform(p1, p2, x, y)
(-146.20443693009113, 21.483194748289176)
```

Why is pyproj giving me different and inaccurate results?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226892/converting-epsg2284-to-epsg4326-with-pyproj) almost immediately after posting this. PyProj specifically expects unit in meters, and the EPSG:3760 projection is in US Feet. This can be solved by making the following modification:

```
>>> p1 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:3760', preserve_units=True)
>>> p2 = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:4326')
>>>
>>> pyproj.transform(p1, p2, x, y)
(-157.74026770737262, 21.391727834432878)
```