# Converting EPSG:2263 to WGS84 using Python Pyproj

Tags: pyproj

I'm trying to convert Projected bounds to WGS84 using Pyproj but getting strange results.

The Projected Bounds are : 909126.0155, 110626.2880, 1610215.3590, 424498.0529

The corresponding WGS84 Bounds (the target) are: -74.2700, 40.4700, -71.7500, 41.3100

The data is from: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83-new-york-long-island-ftus/

```
>>> from pyproj import Proj, transform
>>> inProj  = Proj("+init=EPSG:2236")
>>> outProj = Proj("+init=EPSG:3857")
>>> x1,y1 =  (110626.2880, 909126.0155)
>>> print(transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1))
(-9122788.926222347, 3833518.013375292)
```

The outProj is based on my understanding of what Google Maps uses.

Comment: Try "2263" instead.

Comment: Did for `inProj` and `outProj`. Not getting:  -74.2700, 40.4700

Comment: If you want lat/lon values, use 4269 (NAD83) or 4326 (WGS84) for outProj.

Comment: Both `outProj = Proj("+init=EPSG:4269")` and `outProj = Proj("+init=EPSG:4326")` give me (-76.53059046753678, 48.30210692217332) That's much closer but still off.

Comment: [EPSG:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) is not a geographic CRS and doesn't use lon/lat coordinates, its horizontal units are metres (i.e. not degrees).  You see lon/lat when you click or search in Google Maps as map coordinates are projected on the fly.

Comment: Oh, try swapping x1,y1 values. When I use x = 909126 and y = 110626, in Esri projection engine, I get -74.27 and 40.47 (more or less). Forgive me if you know this, but US coordinates are usually x = easting, y = northing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look [Converting EPSG:2284 to EPSG:4326 with pyproj](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/226940) (and many others...).

**Pyproj expects degrees (lon, lat) or meters (x,y) as units but the unit of [Projection: 2263](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83-new-york-long-island-ftus/html/) is`UNIT["US survey foot"...`, therefore you need to use `preserve_units=True`.**

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
inProj  = Proj("+init=EPSG:2263",preserve_units=True)
outProj = Proj("+init=EPSG:4326") # WGS84 in degrees and not EPSG:3857 in meters)
# swap x,y as mkennedy says
y1,x1 =  (110626.2880, 909126.0155)
print(transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1))
(-74.2700000001129, 40.46999999990434)
```

Control with [GDAL/OSR](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/)

```
from osgeo import osr
inp= osr.SpatialReference()
inp.ImportFromEPSG(2263)
out= osr.SpatialReference()
out.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
transformation = osr.CoordinateTransformation(inp,out)
print(transformation.TransformPoint(x1,y1))
(-74.27000000011289, 40.46999999990432, 0.0)
```

#### New : Now how do I reverse the result?

```
y1,x1 =  (110626.2880, 909126.0155) # and not x1,y1 =
lon,lat = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print(lon, lat)
-74.2700000001129 40.46999999990434
```

Now reverse the result:

```
x, y = transform(outProj,inProj,lon,lat)
print(x,y)
909126.0155000015 110626.28799994898
```

And you get the original values if you use **print(y,x)**

```
print(y,x)
110626.28799994898 909126.0155000015
```

Comment: Now how do I reverse the result? I have swapped `inProj` and `outProj` and experimented with all permutations of `preserve_units` and none gets me back to `(110626.2880, 909126.0155)`. Sorry, I am new to GIS and lack a conceptual grasp.

Comment: If you haven't tried this yet, also try swapping the latitude and longitude values.

Comment: Did you understand the answer correctly (`# swap x,y as mkennedy says`) ? Look at New in my answer